# Is it possible that the frequency of a microwave oven changes because of an error?

Tags: experimental-physics

Somebody complained on a forum, that his microwave oven heats up the plate instead of the food. One explanation that the material of the plate is not suited to microwave ovens. Another explanation that the frequency of the emitted wave changed. Does the design of the emitter allow frequency change without going completely non-functional?

Comment: I have "stoneware", whatever that means, dishes that get hotter than the food does in a microwave.  They are made to keep your food warm longer, but I have to be careful not to burn my fingers on them.

Comment: @AdrianHoward Use two plates then, one stoneware one normal. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A microwave oven generates its radiation via a magnetron which is based on a resonant cavity.

Unless the cavity has been damaged in some way, there is not really any way for it to change its output frequency.

In response to the idea that a plate heats up instead of the food, in fact there are some materials commonly used for plates that readily absorb microwaves and will heat up along with the food.  Melamine is one such example and manufacturers of such products do not recommend their use in microwave ovens.

Comment: The guy just wrote that a week ago he did not have this phenomenon with the same plates and that the oven was repaired a few months ago. I am not sure what else can use this.

Comment: @inf3rno, plates can change over time.  I have a set of "microwave safe" plates that used to work well there.  But over time the glaze cracked and let in water.  Now some of the pates are excellent MW absorbers and get incredibly hot.  This guy could test his hypthothesis by using the plates in some friends' ovens.